# VueJS nested components fail in an NPM package

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack

The example below are using simplified examples.

Both components work separately, however when one is nested within the other neither render on the page.

index.js (entry point)

```
// Test components
import TestComponent from '../src/TestComponent.vue'
import Test2Component from '../src/Test2Component.vue'

export {
    TestComponent,
    Test2Component
}
```

Both `TestComponent` and `Test2Component` will render this way:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <TestComponent></TestComponent>
    <Test2Component></Test2Component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import { TestComponent, Test2Component } from 'myPackage'
Vue.component('TestComponent', TestComponent);
Vue.component('Test2Component', Test2Component);
```

However if I move the `Test2Component` tag into `Test1Component.Vue`:

```
<template>
    <p>This is the TestComponent</p>
    <Test2Component></Test2Component>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Test2Component from './Test2Component';
Vue.component('Test2Component', Test2Component);
console.log( Test2Component)

export default {
  name: 'TestComponent',
  components: {
    Test2Component
  }
}
</script>
```

Not even the `TestComponent.vue` parent component renders.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Do not `import Vue from 'vue'` and modify it, this is a duplicate of the Vue instance. This syntax seems especially restrictive to get it to work when packaging.

Instead add it as a component to `export default`:

```
<script>
import { TestComponent, Test2Component} from 'myPackage'

export default {
  components: {
    'test-component': TestComponent,
    'test2-component': Test2Component
  },
...
</script>
```